# Phalcon: json_encode(array()) return nothing

Tags: php, json, phalcon

So here's my issue:

I am fetching data in my database and want to provide them in `jSON format`.

My `controller` is the following:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $articles = Article::find();

    if (count($articles) > 0) {

        $final_array = array();

        foreach ($articles as $article) {
            $user = Users::find("id = " . $article->getUsersId());

            $current = array('id' => $article->getId(),
                'name' => $article->getName(),
                'replies' => $article->getReplies(),
                'date' => $article->getDate(),
                'illustration' => $article->getIllustration(),
                'content' => $article->getContent(),
                'link' => $article->getLink(),
                'user_id' => $article->getUsersId(),
                'user_name' => $user[0]->getPseudo());

            $final_array[] = $current;
        }

        $result = array('status' => 1,
        'message' => 'article have been downloaded',
        'response' => $final_array);

    } else {
        $result = array('status' => 1,
            'message' => 'no article in the stack');

    }

    $this->view->disable();
    $this->response->setContentType('application/json', 'UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

The view displayed provide `nothing`:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

The trouble doesn't come from my model or SQL request, because if I `var_dump` my result instead by changing my controller like this:

```
[...]
//$this->view->disable();
//$this->response->setContentType('application/json', 'UTF-8');
var_dump($result);
[...]
```

It provides me the following (length doesn't match all the time because I voluntary changed the content which is not interesting in this case):

```
array (size=3)
    'status' => int 1
    'message' => string 'article have been downloaded' (length=28)
    'response' => 
    array (size=1)
        0 => 
        array (size=9)
            'id' => string '1' (length=1)
            'name' => string 'Champion de CAPU' (length=16)
            'replies' => string '0' (length=1)
            'date' => string '2014-06-10 06:22:35' (length=19)
            'illustration' => string 'illustration_link' (length=69)
            'content' => string 'content_text' (length=182)
            'link' => string 'more_link' (length=50)
            'user_id' => string '6' (length=1)
            'user_name' => string 'bathiatus' (length=9)
```

which is what I want to get...

Moreover, I actually did the same in another `controller` in order to provide all the users (so `UserController`, `jGetAllUsersAction`) and it works pretty well (the code is the same except that the table in the database are different).

Comment: I don't know a thing about Phalcon, but switching from using `$this` to `echo` seems suspicious.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: `$this->view->disable();` disable html content in my view (I use it in order to cancel my "default template"); `$this->response->setContentType('application/json', 'UTF-8');` set the content type of the view (so application/json because I want to display json data). Then the echo is just displaying somehting in my view. 

I do not know if this way is the good way, but it works pretty well in the same structure in my other views (with others controllers).

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the issue.

Thank you for the answers, I found that all purposed way to display the view is working (including the one I purposed in my question).

I don't really know which way is the best, but I guess the one in my question is not.

By the way, the issue was that I was trying to inject `special characters` (such as `é`, `è`, `à`, `ë`, ...) in my `Json object`. Indeed, my content is in french.

Json object do not support these kind of characters while printing them with a `var_dump` presents no issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a json response you can do this in your controller:

return $this->response->setJsonContent($result);

Phalcon disables the view and sets the right content type automatically with that. The json_encode is also done, so just put in your $result.

Comment: This is an efficient way of setting both the content-type and content of the response in one go.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default Phalcon needs a view to return the response (in your case the JSON).

Controller code:

```
$this->response->setContentType('application/json', 'UTF-8');
$this->view->setVar("some_var", $result);
```

Then you have to create a view corresponing to the name of the controller and the function
and put there:

```
<?php echo json_encode($some_var); ?>
```

If you don't want to crate a additional view, please use this link for further reference:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/response.html